# Peak voltage calculation

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

Why peak voltage value is important to us, what that peak voltage represents?

I am going to some electronics basics course and I am trying to understand what is the purpose of effective, peak and normal(?) voltage value. Why those three exists, why we just not use voltage we have.

Comment: We don't calculate peak voltage as voltage squared. Your question is flawed.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question, my fault. @Andyaka

Comment: You still talk about squaring the voltage and this is meaningless to this question I believe.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: What is the definition of "voltage we have"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking about AC voltage.

In AC, the voltage is continuously varying from zero, to a positive peak, back down through zero to a negative peak, then back to zero for one full cycle. In North America, commercial AC power produces 60 cycles per second.  In most of the rest of the world, it is 50 cycles per second (Hz).

Since the voltage is continually varying, we have to find some way of specifying the effective (useful) voltage, and that is the Root Mean Square (RMS) value.  This RMS voltage has the same energy or heating effect as the same DC voltage - a 120 volt heater or light will work equally well on 120 V AC RMS or on 120 V DC.  When we speak of an AC voltage, we mean the RMS value, unless specifically stated otherwise.

The voltage at the peaks of a sine wave is about 1.4 times the RMS value (actually the peak voltage is the square root of 2 times RMS -perhaps this is where your "squaring" comes from). If we are viewing the sine wave on an oscilliscope, the peak (or peak-to-peak) voltage is easiest to measure.

The nominal voltage ("normal" in your question, I expect) is the voltage the power company is supposed to deliver to us.  Here in Canada the nominal AC line voltage is 120 V (RMS), but it may vary from perhaps 115 to 125 volts depending on load conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in alternating current (AC), electrons flow back and forth through a conductor at the same periodicity (oscillation):

[image]

**Peak-to-Peak Voltage** is simply the difference in the maximum positive and maximum negative amplitudes of a wave. It describes the largest momentary voltage, which is needed for [amplifier compliance](http://www.princetonappliedresearch.com/Support-Center/FAQ-General/What-is-compliance-voltage.aspx) and electrical breakdown calculations.

**Peak voltage** is half the peak-to-peak voltage. It represents the amplitude of a waveform and shows how large the magnitude of a waveform gets from the 0 horizontal axis line to the crest and trough of the wave.

**RMS** is the most accurate and commonly used of the three. It is a mathematical quantity used to compare AC and DC. In other words, it is the equivalent of DC voltage value required to do the same amount of work (or heat).